# Why is the child class object invoking the parent class field variable in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, field

This is my code, pretty simple and demonstrative:

JVM entrance:

```
class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Dog().start();
    }
}
```

Parent class:

```
public class Animal {
    int num = 100;
    public void call() {
        System.out.println(this.num);
    }

}
```

Child class:

```
 public class Dog extends Animal{
        int num = 10000;
        public void start() {
            this.call();
        }
    }
```

Console output: 100

Why it's 100, not 10000? How to comprehend this?

Answer (score 2):

Your instance has two fields: `Animal::num` and `Dog::num`. `Animal::call()` only knows about `Animal::num`, which is 100.

It is not usually helpful to declare a field in a subclass with the same name as a field in the superclass. Fields are not subject to overriding; and shadowing a name only leads to confusion.

---

Suppose that instead of declaring a new `num` field in `Dog`, you set the existing `num` field to a new value.

```
class Dog extends Animal {
    public Dog() {
        num = 10000;
    }
    public void start() {
        this.call();
    }
}
```

Now if you run `new Dog().start()`, you will find that 10000 is printed. The instance has only one `num` field, declared in `Animal`, and set to 10000 inside `Dog`.